# pointwise limit of finite measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

If there is a sequence of measures $\mu_n$ such that $\mu_n(A) \overset{n}{\rightarrow} \mu(A)$ for all $A$ in the $\sigma$-field and if $\mu_n(\Omega)\leq c$ $(c<\infty)$ for all $n$, then $\mu$ is a measure.
(problem 7, section 1.5 in [Robert Ash](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=GkqQoRpCO2QC))

The above assertion is proved by the Vitali-Hahn-Saks theorem.

What I would like to know is a counter example for the case when the condition,

- $\mu_n(\Omega) \leq c$ for all $n$

is not satisfied.

Comment: So you need to have $\mu_n(\Omega) \to \infty$. In the title there is the assumption that the $\mu_n$ are finite and in the body of the post, this seems to be implicit in the term "measure". Do I understand correctly that your question is: suppose $\mu_n$ are finite measures on the same $\sigma$-field $\Sigma$ and the limit $\mu(A) := \lim_n \mu_n(A)$ exists in $[0,\infty]$ for all $A \in \Sigma$. Does it follow that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive?

Comment: @Martin - Yes, exactly

Comment: @Martin why is it implicit in the term "measure"?

Comment: @DimaMcGreen: I remember being confused and apparently I posted the comment before I cleared up the confusion completely :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take $\mu_n: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be
$$
  \mu_n(A) = \#(A \cap [n,\infty)).
$$
For any bounded set $B$, you have that $\mu_n(B) \rightarrow 0$. But, for any unbounded set $U$, $\mu_n(U) = \infty \rightarrow \infty$.

The limit $\mu$ is not a measure, because
$$
  \mu(\mathbb{N})
  = \infty
  \neq 0
  = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mu(\{n\}).
$$

This example is quite easy to extend to $\mu_n(A) = \lambda(A \setminus K_n)$, where $K_n$ is a sequence of sets such that $K_n \uparrow K$, with $\infty \neq \lambda(K_n) \rightarrow \lambda(K) = \infty$.

In this case, $\mu(K) = \infty$, while $\mu(K_n) = 0$.